# I am trying to format a csv file's Column 'A' to Left Align and save it via python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF2tw.png)Through a CSV module in Python, I'm able to read the contents of my `.csv` file. But my goal is that I have to make one of columns, say Column "A" values to be all "left aligned".

Current values in the column A has values with mixed alignment. **The mixed alignment is because the column has numbers in certain rows and string in certain rows. Numbers by default take right alignment whereas String takes left alignment**. Hence I want to align them with a common alignment using Python and **save the csv file**. Please help.

I have tried CSV writer functions. But  I am unable to find the cell formatting functions.

Comment: Please show an example of a small .csv file that demonstrates what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Csv are just a bunch of values concatenated and separated by a comma, so indentation doesn't make sense. Are you sure the values you're writing to the file don't have leading spaces giving the impression that they are indented?

Comment: @glibdud: I have attached the screenshot as well as edited the description of my question.  Hope now I have shared clearly what I want to accomplish. Please help.

Comment: @ElSam: I am talking about the .csv files which opens in Microsoft Excel. My User opens the .csv file in Excel and he is seeing the one column with mixed indentations. I have edited my description as well as attached the screenshots. Please check and let me know. There are no leading spaces.

Comment: As you mentioned, this issue is not due to csv per se, it's in how Excel renders the data. You can't do much about that if your file is csv. You can try maybe to create a xlxs file instead. You would get to control how your data gets formatted.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't really a concept of "formatting" in CSV files. If all you're going for is consistency, though, saving the numbers as strings (by putting quotes around them) might do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying there are varying amounts of whitespace on each line? What you can do is strip all whitespace from the beginning of each line then add a tab if so desired.

```py
import csv

text = """   1,2,3
    a,b,c
  d,e,f"""
print(text)

lines = text.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print('\t' + ','.join(row).lstrip())
```

Output:

Varying indentations

```
   1,2,3
    a,b,c
  d,e,f
```

All aligned

```
    1,2,3
    a,b,c
    d,e,f
```